# Expo EAS local build: Plugin Error: Failed to resolve plugin for module <module-name> relative to <your-build-directory>

Tags: react-native, plugins, expo, eas

I have a few plugins in my `app.config.js` file and getting the following error causing the local EAS build to fail. When I remove the first plugin, the same error occurs for the next one, so the error seems to be irrelevant to that exact plugin, but rather to any plugins. Using expo skd 49; expo version 6.3.10; eas-cli/4.1.0 darwin-x64 node-v19.6.1

Any ideas?

```
[READ_APP_CONFIG]
PluginError: Failed to resolve plugin for module "expo-localization" relative to "easBuild/build"
    at resolvePluginForModule (/Users/behnam/.npm/_npx/7b94c2150570f17f/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/utils/plugin-resolver.js:72:11)
    at resolveConfigPluginFunctionWithInfo (/Users/behnam/.npm/_npx/7b94c2150570f17f/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/utils/plugin-resolver.js:152:7)
    at resolveConfigPluginFunction (/Users/behnam/.npm/_npx/7b94c2150570f17f/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/utils/plugin-resolver.js:143:7)
    at withStaticPlugin (/Users/behnam/.npm/_npx/7b94c2150570f17f/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withStaticPlugin.js:87:70)
    at /Users/behnam/.npm/_npx/7b94c2150570f17f/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withPlugins.js:30:84
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at withPlugins (/Users/behnam/.npm/_npx/7b94c2150570f17f/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withPlugins.js:30:18)
    at withConfigPlugins (/Users/behnam/.npm/_npx/7b94c2150570f17f/node_modules/@expo/config/build/plugins/withConfigPlugins.js:36:47)
    at fillAndReturnConfig (/Users/behnam/.npm/_npx/7b94c2150570f17f/node_modules/@expo/config/build/Config.js:217:78)
    at getConfig (/Users/behnam/.npm/_npx/7b94c2150570f17f/node_modules/@expo/config/build/Config.js:268:12)

Build failed
Skipping cleanup, ./easBuild won't be removed.
Unknown error. See logs for more information.
npx exited with non-zero code: 1
    Error: build command failed.
```

Plugins in `app.config.js`:

```
        plugins: [ 'expo-localization',
            [
                'expo-updates',
                {
                    username: 'onrun',
                },
            ],
            [
                'expo-camera', {
                    cameraPermission: 'To let you add photos to your profile or events.',
                },
            ],
            [
                'expo-build-properties',
                {
                    ios: {
                        flipper: true,
                    },
                },
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: Could you have solved this?

Comment: @MehmetKaplan I think so. Did you check the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the build directory seems to be the cause of the error. When I take away the local build directory by unsetting the env variable as below, the build went okay.

`unset EAS_LOCAL_BUILD_WORKINGDIR`

Comment: Could you be more specific?